# How high did Philae bounce?

Tags: gravity, low-energy-transfer, philae

The [Philae lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae_(spacecraft)) bounced off [67P/C-G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/67P/Churyumov%E2%80%93Gerasimenko) due to low gravity, but how high did it actually bounce?

Comment: I wouldn't say the bouncing was due to low gravity... the bouncing was because the harpoons didn't fire and the landing thruster didn't go off.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym indeed [Why did Philae the comet lander bounce?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8120/12102)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that at first they thought the harpoon triggers were wired wrong, but it turned out they were fine -- it was the explosive charges that weren't working. (Or at least that's what we now believe since nobody could actually go check for sure.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to ESA's 2014 article [Three touchdowns for Rosetta’s lander](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Rosetta/Three_touchdowns_for_Rosetta_s_lander), Philae rebounded off the surface at 38 cm/s and reached a maximum altitude of approximately 1 km above the surface. Note that escape velocity from the comet was ~44 cm/s.

The bigger problem was that Philae detected the initial impact and shut down its reaction wheel, which caused a momentum transfer that started it spinning and probably made the subsequent bouncing and tumbling much worse than it otherwise might have been.

Comment: ... which corresponds to bouncing an impressive 16 cm here on Earth.

Comment: @asdfex That's a good point.  A six-inch rebound off a hard surface is actually a pretty big impact for a metal structure that weighs about as much as a washing machine.

Answer (score 1):

The Philae lander bounced off comet 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko twice. After the first landing attempt, it bounced to an altitude of about 1 kilometer (0.62 miles) and then touched down again at a different location on the comet’s surface. The exact height of the second bounce is not precisely known, but it was much lower than the initial bounce. The low gravity of the comet contributed to the bouncing effect.

Comment: References to support the claims would improve the answer.

Comment: Hi Amber, as well as references, please always see if existing answers have more info than you plan to write. Here, Darth's answer has more info, a reference, and as you can see, is highly upvoted.